# How to Generate twitter oauth_signature in Ruby

Tags: ruby, oauth, twitter, twitter-oauth, rhomobile

How to Generate twitter oauth_signature in Ruby, I am not using any library like(Oauth, Twitter, twitter_oauth)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite ambiguos.

You should start by reading [Twitter dev's documentation on OAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth). There's even an [example](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth/single-user-with-examples#ruby) there with the [OAuth gem](http://oauth.rubyforge.org/). I used this gem for my code too and was able to authenticate with Twitter's API. After trying out some solution, come back for more specific questions.

Answer (score 0):

I made a small [twitter command line app](http://github.com/pbosetti/twt): you can have a look at the code to see a more complex example.